# Как бороться с фиктивными отзывами Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Имею дело с завистниками. [Здесь](https://play.google.com/about/comment-posting-policy.html?hl=ru&rd=1) сказано, что оставлять фиктивные отзывы является нарушением правил.

Значит как-то можно их обжаловать? Кто-то сталкивался с накруткой негативных отзывов на ваше приложение? Как вы с этим боретесь?

Comment: Как полумера - выпускайте фиктивное обновление, тогда к отзыву будет приписка, что он для старой версии. Что, возможно, немного уменьшит его значимость в глазах посетителя.

Comment: Врядли пользователи сильно парятся комментами о версии. Темболее что коментов не оставляют. Просто ставят звезду и все. + на сколько я понимаю в поиске приложение тоже падает и найти его тяжелее становится. + я к примеру даже не считаю нужным читать комменты от приложегия с рейтингом 4.4 я лучше устаноалю и почитаю что-то в районе 4.8. Собственно как у меня было до этого. Хотелось бы вообще удалить фиктивные оценки

Answer (score 6, accepted):

К сожалению, никто не будет с этим возиться и разбираться в индивидуальном порядке. Такие люди работают вполне законно регистрируют кучу аккаунтов и в честном порядке ставят отзывы.

Это так же как задачка в С++, как определить случайную строку от мусора? Никак. Это просто набор байтов.

**Что можно сделать?**

Отзывы накручиваются, чтобы лишить покупательной способности и не попасть в топ.

1) Рейтинг/попадание в топ считается по формуле, которую вычислить вряд ли получится. Но можно вычислить определенные коэффициенты, которые сильнее влияют на формулу. И давить на них - тогда отзывы написанные вам ни на что не будут влиять.

2) Покупательная способность, когда люди видят негативные отзывы. Тут сделать ничего не получится. Если только на IOs есть возможность последний отзыв ставить положительный. На андройде почему то они сортируются от плохих к хорошим.

Вы должны понимать, что мобильный рынок - очень специфический рынок. Он сильно зависит от моды. И если ваше приложение уже прижали, стоит задуматься стоит ли воевать? Мне очень жаль, но тут победит у кого больше ресурсов = денег.

PS Я бы делал следующее app, чтобы с него уже пустить трафик на первое. :)